# Debugging Maven's "The artifact has no valid ranges"

Tags: maven-2

We're using Maven at work at quite regularly we get the error message "The artifact has no valid ranges". After a long time of Googling and experimenting I realised what this error message means: The artifact *does* have valid ranges, just too many of them.

For example, my master POM has a dependency on superframework v.1.0 only, but there is also a transitive dependency on superframework v.0.5-0.9.

Until now, whenever I had such a problem I've looked at the (very cryptic) error message and sorta guessed which POM I needed to change - basically a lot of trial an error. The problem is that `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't work if you have a dependency resolution problem.

The Eclipse plugin *sometimes* helps a little, but sometimes it is way off.

Any tips on how to resolve these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the expected answer but my advice would be to actually **not** use dependency ranges as they worsen build reproducibility.

I prefer to use fixed versions (which also make dependencies conflicts resolution easier, see the note at the bottom of [9.4.3. Dependency Version Ranges](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges.html)) and use intensively [the Dependency Convergence report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependency-convergence-mojo.html) to manage them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I will try to get the word out at work.

Comment: The link in the answer seems not to work anymore, the new one is:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to my question but rather a word of advice. I learned something new since askin the question: the order in which dependencies are listed in the POM files, much to my surprise, *does* matter.

So, if you include a dependency on

```
superframework [0.5,1.5)
```

it will fetch the latest available version, say 1.1.

If you then have a transitive dependency further down that includes

```
superframework [0.5, 1.0)
```

Maven will generate this misleading error, since it will not select anything other than the 1.1 it already has, even though it could just select 0.9 without producing a version conflict. If you swap the order, weirdly, it works.

Am I right in thinking that this is a flaw in Maven's behaviour?

Comment: This might be related to the way Maven resolves dependencies (and conflicts), see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution. Another good reason to not use ranges IMHO.